# Count Query on same Column

Tags: sql

Following are two SQL tables :

- Classroom (1-100),
- Gender (male/female)

I want to  count of each gender in each classroom. I expect Query results as:

```
Classroom | CountMale | CountFemale
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
```

How can I get the count?

Comment: You'll need a `GROUP BY` and a `PIVOT` of some kind. But please tag which RDBMS you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT Classroom, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountMale,
      SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountFemale
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Classroom
```

Change the literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Classroom,
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountMale,
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountFemale
FROM t
GROUP BY Classroom
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you spot me the tutorial for this?